# Google Helvetica font not getting load with css2 API (403 error)

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm trying to import google fonts in wordpress website. all other fonts are getting load but only Helvetica font is not loading. saying 403 error. I have tried following.

**With multiple request :**

```css
<br/>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');<br/>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');<br/>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Helvetica:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
```

**With single request:**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap&family=Helvetica:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
```

And one important thing, it is working on local but only not working on remote.

**Note :** I can't use the link tag. i can only import fonts using import of **css**.

Comment: Can you report the entire error? because if you copy the font url in the browser you can see it

Comment: Should i add screen shot of response header ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is no Google font named `Helvetica`. So change your code to this

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-9');
```

Comment: Are you sure?[https://fonts.google.com/?query=helvetica](https://fonts.google.com/?query=helvetica)

Comment: But why is it working on local.

Comment: Because Helvetica is a default font on Windows

Comment: But i can see the request response in network tab. it is also giving response for Helvetica

Comment: @Sfili_81 It's not a google font. https://imgur.com/a/k7d9kkG

Comment: Did my code work By the way? @MohitSwami

Comment: click to my link or post the OP link for helvetica and see it

Comment: @ŕ̷͉ge̸ḓ̶̅i̷t it saying "blocked:mixed" in network tab